# OpenCV put() Java/Scala is Slow, How to optimize?

Tags: java, scala, opencv, image-processing, optimization

I have an image processing server and I am trying to work through the following:

```scala
    logger info "calling detect"
    // read from file, pretty fast
    val bytes = new FileInputStream(frame getPath) readAllBytes()
    // I can tell because this line executes immediately
    logger info (s"the image was read as ${bytes length}")
    // also trivial
    val imageMat = new Mat(frame.width, frame.height, 1)
    logger info "constructed empty matrix..."
    // this takes a long time, as I cannot see the log line that follows
    imageMat put (0, 0, bytes)
    logger info s"read image as matrix: ${imageMat dump()}"
```

This snippet loads an image (.bgr888) from as an array of bytes, creates an empty matrix with the width/length of the image (which I have from a gRPC request), then populates the matrix with the values of the byte array. Only that last step takes forever.

I tried wrapping the byte array as a ByteBuffer and passing directly to the matrix constructor but that violated some C++ assertion about the data being 0 or null, which is weird to me since clearly the data is neither, but I am not a C++ dev so idk what's going on with that.

Comment: can you add the code you tried using the ByteBuffer?.

Answer (score 0):

This was a silly mistake on my part; the last log line dumps the contents of the matrix which must be loaded, then formatted, then printed to console. that's what violates my gRPC timeout configurations.